# Connection Times out whenever a custom client ID is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I've been learning AWS IOT Core and I was using the Python starter kit to publish and receive messages. It works fine when I use "basicPubSub" (the default clientID in the sample program) as the client ID but as soon as I change the client ID to lets say "client1234" it disconnects and times out

Logs:

```
basicPubSub:
```

https://pastebin.com/TbenrNfe

```
client1234:
```

https://pastebin.com/nrhbkb6N

Comment: Tip: Copy the relevant sections from the links and put them in the question

Comment: Have you rerun `basicPubsub_CognitoSTS.py` to tell it your new client id?

Comment: I didn't actually understand it's code as there are no tutorials available on the Internet. I do have an AWS Educate account but I don't know how to clarify any queries that I have there.

Comment: @blt forgot to mention you